# Is there a KVM GUI for headless Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I want to be able to install and run virtual machines on my headless Ubuntu server, but I don't want to use the cli as there are far to many switches to memorize that can create far to many typo errors, what I'm looking for is maybe a 3rd party GUI that can perform the same functions as virt-manager, without installing a desktop GUI.

Comment: I forgot to mention I use SSH via PuTTY from a windoze workstation to access the Ubuntu server, and using an SSH console I would like to create and manage virtual machines on the headless Ubuntu server via a GUI that doesn't require a desktop GUI.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the new information.

Comment: [Kimchi](http://www.ubuntuboss.com/ubuntu-server-18-04-as-a-hypervisor-using-kvm-and-kimchi-for-vm-management/) fell out of the archive, but might still work for what you want

Comment: Just what I was looking for, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run [virt-manager](https://virt-manager.org/download/) on your Windows machine and visually manage your remote libvirtd server.

Comment: I tried Windows virt-manager, and it seems it can only connect to either a spice or vnc graphicall server, which means I would need to install a complete desktop GUI on the server.

I settled for Kimchi with the wok interface.

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to install in your Windows environment the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Then download an appliance/VM (however you want to call it) from the Windows Store (there's Ubuntu, Fedora, Alpine).

Then from that linux instance, execute virt-manager. Have it display its windows to you with VCXsrv, an X11 distribution compiled with VisualC++ that runs well on Windows.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC0c4.png)

Comment: [not anymore](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-heart-linux/)